# First-Order Phase Transition

Tags: solid-state-physics, phase-transition, gas, phase-diagram, liquid-state

When the density/volume abruptly changes (isobar/isothermal) while providing a sufficient latent heat to the system, is this variation related to a high compression/expansion as it is illustrated to the continuity equation? Or it's related to the fact that molecules will have more degrees of freedom due to the extra energy given at microscopic scale?

Thanks